# jquery form submit

Tags: jquery

I have a few forms with the IDs `comment_addXXX`. I want to submit all of these at once, rather than individually submit each form.

i.e. Can I simplify something like:

```
$('#comment_add1111').submit();
$('#comment_add111122').submit();
$('#comment_add1222111').submit();
$('#comment_add11133331').submit();
```

Into something like:

```
$('#comment_add*').submit();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the starts with selector

```
$('form[id^=comment_add]').each(function() {
    $(this).submit();
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 0):

or example, consider the HTML:
Example :

```
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
<div id="other">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```

The event handler can be bound to the form:

```
$('#target').submit(function() {
  alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
  return false;
});
```

other the id of a control:

```
$('#other').click(function() {
  $('#target').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't quotation marks necessary, Petah?

```
$('form[id^="comment_add"]').each(function() {
    $(this).submit();
});
```